# PHP: How to preg_split by full stop?

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I want to take a string and split it (or explode it) into an array by full-stops (periods).

I used to have:

```
$processed_data = explode(".", $raw_data);
```

but this removes the full-stop.

Researching, I found `preg_split`, so tried:

```
$processed_data = preg_split('\.', $raw_data, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

with both `\.` and `\\.`

but try as I might, I cannot find a way to properly include the full-stop.

Would anyone know the right way to do this?

The expected result is:

The string

```
$raw_data = 'This is my house. This is my car. This is my dog.';
```

Is broken into an array by full-stop, eg:

```
array("This is my house.", "This is my car.", "This is my dog.")
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need the `.`?  You can always add it back into the array with a simple loop.

Comment: Patterns require delimiters in PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Comment: after getting explode then you can add the full stops into each exploded array element manually, simple way,

Comment: `preg_match_all` might be easier, https://eval.in/762249

Comment: @Forbs wouldn't that be a little inelegant though? (I don't actually know, just asking)

Comment: @chris85 sorry, no luck there either

Comment: @MeltingDog Can you explain? That looked like a functional example.

Comment: @chris85 I tried your exmaple with `'/([^.]+?\.)\s*/'` and other regex dot variations, but, simply, no results appeared in the array.

Comment: @MeltingDog Not sure how you were using but works here, https://eval.in/762294. The third parameter is the assignment. Use the first index, the `0` index could have trailing whitespace, or if you don't care about that use the `0` and you dont need the capture group. In the future it'd be good to include your example strings at the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To split a string into sentences:

```
preg_match_all('~\s*\K[^.!?]*[.!?]+~', $raw_data, $matches);
$processed_data = $matches[0];
```

Note: if you want to handle edge cases like abbreviations, a simple regex doesn't suffice, you need to use nltk or any other nlp tool with a dictionary.

Comment: I think that's close! Would you know how to get it working with a dot? Currently, this seems to split it, but at random places.

Comment: @MeltingDog: sorry I have forgotten to escape the dot *(that has a special meaning otherwise)*.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte your examples don't work as you might expect. https://eval.in/762283

Comment: Oh man, this is close! It just splits the values and include the dot before each array item, as per @Rob's example. Would you know a way to have it include the delimiter after each value?

Comment: @Rob: to be clear, I don't know actually what is the expected result.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I'll add an expected result above.

Comment: I'd have thought OP would want the full-stop in the grammatically correct place within the sentence.

Comment: @MeltingDog: are you trying to split a string into sentences?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte yes, the ultimate goal is to split a paragraph of sentences into an array (by '.') to later turn it into a bullet point list. I've added an example in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Downvote removed and replaced with upvote for fixing answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

```
$string = preg_replace("/\.\s?([A-Z])/", "*****$1", $raw_data);
$array = explode("*****", $string);
```